# cumulative MSI entries for Java updates?

Tags: java, registry, windows-installer

I'm deploying Java Update 7.17 through Local Update Publisher/WSUS in my domain. Because the deploy doesn´t work with the extracted MSI files through a "command line error" I had to use the *.exe files and add the MSI Code of the package in the "installed/insallable" rules manually. Works fine for now.

My question is now about future java updates. I´m about to deploy them the same way. So when I deploy the new Version with the new MSI code will the older entry (from 7.17) persist in the registry? Cause the updater will uninstall the previous version. If thats not the case I need to involve the 7.17 MSI code (and newer ones) in all future "install/installable" rules of the packages.
I´m hoping the MSI registry entries of java are kind of cumulative and won´t be removed in case of an update - so that I don´t have to take the "older" updates offline. Else they un-/install each other over and over again.

Can somebody approve this or the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way that the Java Update MSI does it's updates. If they use major upgrades (which is very likely) then the MSI `ProductCode` will change with every release. If they use minor upgrades (which is less likely) then then MSI `ProductCode` will remain the same.

Comment: that kinda goes around my question cause if its the case that the MSI code changes then I still want to know if the newer one includes the previous or deletes it or just remains it in the registry.

i´m going to test it myselfe step by step and let anybody know who´s interested.

thanks anyway.